# Mysql will not restart properly after changing config

Tags: mysql

I have just updated the my.cnf file on my linux machine and now my mysql installation will not restart without error messages. I get

```
'the server quit without updating pid file'
```

These are the lines i added

```
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

What the the pid and sock files. They didnt exist but i created them my using these commands

```
sudo touch mysqld.pid
sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld.pid
```

However if i take these lines out the server restarts and stops just fine

Comment: "Without error messages" means that all logs are empty or only that nothing gets printed on console?

Comment: You don't need to create `pid` and `socket` files these are created automatically, Once `MySQL` starts successfully

Answer (score 1):

you've created a pid file by using `touch`. A pid files indicates a running process. Mysql will not start because a pid file already exists; created by you. Just remove the pid file.

Same goes for the sock.